# Deleting deep association in CakePHP

Tags: cakephp

I have a `Courses` model that gives me this array:

```
[User] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 4
                    [username] => itaita
                    [password] => sdfasdgadgadfgsfdgsdgsdgsdgdsg
                    [email] => itaita@xyz.com
                    [name] => 
                    [role] => admin
                    [hash_change_password] => 
                    [created] => 2014-03-16 21:06:48
                    [modified] => 2014-03-16 21:06:48
                    [CoursesUser] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [user_id] => 4
                            [course_id] => 1
                        )

                )

        )
```

I want to create a subscribe/unsubscribe button that will delete the `CoursesUser` where `id=this user id` and `course_id = this course` but I don't know how to access it from the Courses controller and view.

Currently I have:

```
public function unsubscribe($id = null) {
        $this->Course->id = $id;
        $userid = CakeSession::read("Auth.User.id");

        if (!$this->Course->exists()) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid course'));
        }
        $this->request->onlyAllow('post', 'delete');
        if ($this->Course->User->delete(array('CoursesUser.user_id'=> $userid), false)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The course has been deleted.'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The course could not be deleted. Please, try again.'));
        }
        return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
    }
```

But this deletes the user.

I know the problem is here: `$this->Course->User->delete` but I don't know how to change this to address the `CoursesUser` array.

Help!

Comment: Is your `CursesUser` model related to `Curse`? I am guessing you want to only delete entry in that model, since `User hasAndBelongsToMany Curse` right? So you should be able to do something like: `$this->Curse->CursesUser->delete(...)`;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this:

$this->Course->User->CoursesUser->deleteAll(array('CoursesUser.user_id' => $user_id, 'CoursesUser.course_id' => $id), false);

Basically, assuming that you have your model relations set up correctly, this will delete only the CoursesUser rows that match the user_id that you have retrieved from auth that also have the course_id supplied to the action.

Comment: I tried this - but it says something about trying to do that on a non-object.

Comment: I think it's because I need to somehow identify which ->User out of the array of many users that the Course could have.

Comment: You don't have to, basically all you want is to delete a record from CoursesUser. You want to delete any record that:  
  
- has user_id = the user's id that you pass along.  
- has course_id = the course ID that you pass along.  
  
It could be that your relationships are not set up correctly, in that case, could you try this instead?  
  
$this->loadModel('CoursesUser');  
$this->CoursesUser->deleteAll(array('CoursesUser.user_id' => $user_id, 'CoursesUser.course_id' => $id), false);  
  
and see if that fixes it?